# Not Able To Create Multiple SSH User In Alpine container

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, devops, alpine-linux

i am trying to enable bastion on Fargate. So by default I do able to create and successfully able to do SSH with my private key. But when i try to add another user, its gets created but again when i am trying to do SSH with my private key with a second user its just prompts for a password to login.::

```
FROM alpine:3.8
WORKDIR /home
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ADD config_script.sh .
RUN chmod 700 config_script.sh
RUN chmod +x config_script.sh
ADD bootstrap.sh .
RUN chmod +x bootstrap.sh
RUN apk add wget

RUN wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64 && \
    mv jq-linux64 /usr/local/bin/jq && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jq
RUN echo "installing dependencys..." && \
    apk --update \
        add \
            curl \
            openssh \
            python \
            tini \
            sudo \
    && \
    echo "installing aws cli" && \
    apk add --no-cache \
            py3-pip \
        && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
        && pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
            awscli \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*  && \
    aws --version && \
    echo "creating ops user" && \
    adduser -D -s /bin/sh ops && \
    adduser ops root && \
    passwd ops -d '*' && \
    mkdir -p /home/ops/.ssh/ && \
    mkdir -p /var/log/bastion/ && \
    chown -R ops /home/ops/.ssh/
RUN  echo "configuring aws cli"  \
        && mkdir ~/.aws \
        && touch ~/.aws/config \
        && chmod 600 ~/.aws/config \
        && echo "[profile default]"                             > ~/.aws/config \
        && echo "aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"         >> ~/.aws/config \
        && echo "aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/config
RUN echo '%root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers    
RUN /home/config_script.sh
ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/sbin/tini", "--" ]
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

entrypoint.sh =::

```
    echo "downloading user keys..." 
mkdir authorized_keys 
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/user-keys/ authorized_keys/ 
cat authorized_keys/* > .ssh/authorized_keys 
chown -R ops ./ 
chmod -R 0600 authorized_keys/ 
chmod 0700 .ssh/ 
chmod 0644 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

so till here everything works well.

Now when i try to add another user::

```
    if [[ "$USER_NAME" = $USER_NAME ]]; then
        # Create a user account if it does not already exist
        cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -qx $USER_NAME
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "creating $USER_NAME user"
       adduser -g "$USER_NAME" $USER_NAME
       echo "$USER_NAME ALL=(ALL) ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$USER_NAME && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USER_NAME
    for u in $USER_NAME; do for g in root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel floppy dialout tape video; do addgroup $u $g; done;done
    
        mkdir -m 700 /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh
        chown -R $USER_NAME /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/
        chown -R $USER_NAME /home/$USER_NAME/
##adding key::
cat  /home/$USER_NAME/authorized_keys/ >  /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chmod -R 0600 /home/$USER_NAME/authorized_keys/
        chmod 644 /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chown $USER_NAME:$USER_NAME /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Usually a Docker image packages up just a single program and its immediate dependencies; it doesn't have multiple users, ssh keys, or sudo.  Would a virtual machine with a standard init system and Linux userspace fit your needs better?

Comment: got it. yes that kind of machine would be fit but here there will be security items that will be needed to be get configured if we just use VM-based Bastion host. Do you think using Ubuntu image will help in having multiple ssh session? @DavidMaze